# Problems with administrator roles: "Access denied"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can not give access to the user management page to the administrator

I'm studying ASP .Net Core and I'm stuck at this point. I have reviewed the code, ensuring that the same name referenced classes, and testing different configurations for Startup.cs services, but can not find the way. 
I am following the tutorial called "The Little ASP.NET Core Book". I'm stuck on the "Authorization with roles" point

- This is my controller:

  ```
  namespace ASPDotNetCoreTodo.Controllers
  {
  //La configuración de la propiedad Roles en el atributo
  //[Authorize] garantizará que el usuario tenga que iniciar sesión y se le
  //asigne el rol de Administrador para poder ver la página.

  [Authorize(Roles = Constants.AdministratorRole)]
  public class ManageUsersController : Controller
  {
      private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

      public ManageUsersController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
      {
          _userManager = userManager;
      }
      public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
      {
          var admins = (await _userManager
              .GetUsersInRoleAsync("Administrator"))
              .ToArray();

          var everyone = await _userManager.Users
              .ToArrayAsync();

          var model = new ManageUsersViewModel
          {
              Administrators = admins,
              Everyone = everyone
          };
          return View(model);
      }
  }
  ```
- The Model:

  ```
  namespace ASPDotNetCoreTodo.Models
  {
      public class ManageUsersViewModel
      {
          public ApplicationUser[] Administrators { get; set; }
          public ApplicationUser[] Everyone { get; set; }
      }
  }
  ```
- The Startup.cs file:

  ```
  namespace ASPDotNetCoreTodo
  {
  public class Startup
  {
      public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
      {
          Configuration = configuration;
      }

      public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

      // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
          services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>                  options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

          //  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
          //      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
          //      .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

          services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                  .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                  .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                  ;


      services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
      {
          // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
          options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
          options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
      });

      //Añadimos servicio de aplicaciones
          services.AddScoped<ITodoItemService, TodoItemService>();

          services.AddAuthentication(); 

          services.AddMvc();
      }

      // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
      {
          if (env.IsDevelopment())
          {
              app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
              app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
          }
          else
          {
              app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
              app.UseHsts();
          }

          app.UseHttpsRedirection();
          app.UseStaticFiles();
          app.UseCookiePolicy();

          app.UseAuthentication();

          app.UseMvc(routes =>
          {
              routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "default",
                  template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
          });
      }
  }
  ```

The point is that I'm having troubles getting the authorization for the ManageUsersController to work. When the line [Authorize(Roles = Constants.AdministratorRole)] is used above the class, my test administrator account is not able to access the page, even though the same constant is used to filter the user accounts in the DB and in the menu and put them in a table (inside the ManageUsers view) as expected.

I have update .NET Core to 2.2, and the project to...

Anyway, this is my GitHub: https://github.com/erniker/LearningASPNETCoreAndTests

Comment: It's a very common tutorial - you *don't* need to include so many details (for example, `using` statements and view don't really help to troubleshoot. What is not clear - how do you know that the logged in user is indeed Administrator? Do you get any error? What exactly do you mean by *I can not give access*? (also, take a look at the formatting changes that were done for you. please make sure that your code is readable)

Comment: HI Felix.
I know that de user is logged because I can see the TODOlist page of each users that are logged.
I Know that the user that I want to use to see the Manage Users page is administrator because y have a funtion that create the admin account… and not, I dont gent any error; is just that when y try to see  Manage Users page from admin acount, the only page I see is one that sais "Acces denied"

Answer (score 0):

do you have a login function for the admin? or a way to authenticate the user?

if not then this is why because the app is trying to access a function meant for the Role=Constants.AdministratorRole while authenticating from the cookie (since you used cookie authentication) but when the authentication tries to check for the current user it will find that there is no authenticated user which will not allow the client to access the page.

consider the following actions:

- first in the startup.cs add the cookie policy after adding the authentication (apparently order matters) and set the authentication scheme to cookie authentication to tell the app to use authentication from the cookie. i usually use the following:

  ```
      //add authentication service with an encrypted cookie
      services.AddAuthentication(options => {

          options.DefaultScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
          options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

      }).AddCookie(options => {
          options.SlidingExpiration = true;
          options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

          options.Cookie.Name = "ClientCookie";
      });
  ```
- consider adding a login function to authenticate the user as admin such that the app can properly authenticate the user. i use something like this:

  ```
  public class AuthController : Controller
  {
  private readonly string authScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;


  [HttpPost("[action]")]
  public IActionResult Login([FromBody]JObject body)
  {



      //Gets inputs from Request Body
      string userName = body[UserModelConstants.Username].ToString();
      string password = body[UserModelConstants.Password].ToString();

      //use the username and password to check if the user is ok or not
      //then get his claim from database or fill them yourself but make sure to have a role type claim with the value "Administrator" for the admin user
      List<Claim> claims = getUserClaims();

      //now you have to create the user identity and principle
      ClaimsIdentity CI = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
          ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
      ClaimsPrincipal CP = new ClaimsPrincipal(CI);


      return SignIn(CP, authScheme);//sign in the user so it can be checked when the user is being authorized to access the function.

  }
  ```

this works fine for me every time i create a project but maybe you would like to tweak it a bit for your preference or maybe select other types of authentication.

Comment: Hi Hammadi. thanks for the information, but, as you can see un my startup flie, I dint use cookie authentication.
Anyway, I dont want do anything so far from the tutorial, and all that you told me above is still confuse for me...

PD: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: @JoséPabloMedinaGrande - your English is fine; the problem is that you don't want to listen for advice - not your English. The error is **not** in the code that you posted; it's either in your Authentication controller, or the way your middleware is configured. You say that *you know that the user is Administrator*; but the application gives you *Access denied* error - which tells that it disagrees with you...

Comment: Sorry, but its difficult for me following @Hammadi, advise, however, i tried it, without success.
I have added more information

Answer (score 0):

Well, for any reasons, after upgrade .net Core to 2.2 version, It seem that still fail, however, runnig the Project from VS2019, instead of VSCode, it seem that the Project Works nice.